# Fixed aspect ratio with a fixed height

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

Hey so I have an aspect ratio of 4:7 (4w:7h) which is maintained like this:

```css
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      padding-top: 175%;
    }
    .content {
      position:  absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
          
          <p>This is the content.</p>
    
        </div>
      </div>
```

It maintains its aspect ratio perfectly well, but I want to stop the height of the wrapper from going over 100%. At the moment if I keep expanding the window, then the wrapper will just overflow off the page (specifically the `:before` part). It never goes over 100% width which is good, but I want to do the same for the height as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `overflow:hidden;` on `.wrapper`

Comment: Yeah, but that's just hiding the wrapper, not adjusting its height. If I have content in that wrapper then it's going to cut off the content.

Comment: `.wrapper { overflow: hidden } .content { overflow: auto }`?

Comment: @Oriol That will still just cut off the content

Comment: No, it will show a scrollbar if necessary

Comment: As I said, I want to make sure the wrapper maintains its aspect ratio but doesn't go over 100%. Let's say you make a square div, I want it to always be a square and not go outside of the width or height.